# When 31st April or 29th Feb for non-leap year the date inserted in Oracle table it is 30 April instead of 31st and 28th Feb instead of 29th

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Is this behavior expected? And why?

When 31st April or 29th February for non-leap year the date inserted in Oracle table it is 30 April instead of 31st and 28th February instead of 29th February.

Comment: It's not the behavior I would expect.  I would expect an error to be thrown.

Comment: Why don't you show us the `insert` statement you're executing?

Comment: I believe it should throw error and not expected behavior . Thanks Dan

Comment: @CodeHungry - of course it should throw an error. So if you're not getting an error it is down to the specifics of your insert statement. Hence, you need to post the actual insert statement and some sample data which reproduces your problem. Or don't ,and make us guess what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to capture the error if the date is invalid.

Let's say you ran below script. Obviously, an error will be thrown because the date is invalid.

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT='MM/DD/YYYY';

DECLARE
    v_date DATE;
BEGIN
    v_date := '04/31/2018'';
END;
/

Error report -
ORA-01839: date not valid for month specified
ORA-06512: at line 4
01839. 00000 -  "date not valid for month specified"
```

If you want capture the error, you can do it by defining an exception.

```
DECLARE
    v_date DATE;
    ORA_1839 EXCEPTION;
    PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(ORA_1839, -1839);
BEGIN
    v_date := '04/31/2018';
EXCEPTION
    WHEN ORA_1839 THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ERROR 1839 HAD CAUGHT');
END;
/
```

Comment: `ORA-01830` This error is a formatting error caused by **casting the string** `'31-APR-2018'` to a date, not the fact that it's an invalid date. You should get the same error if you cast `'31-MAY-2018'` to a date without using an explicit mask, because it seems your default date format is not `DD-MON-YYYY`.

Comment: @APC, thanks for the correction, modified my answer above

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, if we do this ...

```
select date '2018-02-29' from dual;
```

... or this ...

```
select date '2018-04-31' from dual;
```

... Oracle will definitely hurl `ORA-01847: day of month must be between 1 and last day of month`.

But Oracle handles things when we do this :

```
select add_months(date '2018-01-29', 1) from dual; 
select add_months(date '2018-03-31', 1) from dual;
```

Instead of hurling an error Oracle returns the last day of the next month, `2018-02-28` and `2018-04-30` respectively. So it's being helpful and catching a silly error caused by the quirks of the Western calendar, which seems fair enough (although you may choose to disagree). However, it has one, er,  *interesting* side-effect. This ...

```
select add_months(date '2018-02-28', 1) from dual;
```

... returns `2018-03-31` because *last day of month*, which may not always be expected or desired.

Here is [a SQLFiddle to play with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f3d61/1).

As @zirhc points out, INTERVAL behaves differently, and this ...

```
select date '2018-01-29' + interval '1' month  from dual;
```

... will hurl the expected [ORA-01839: date not valid for month specified](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f3d61/2).

Comment: This only works for add_months, `to_Date('31.01.2018') + interval '1' month` returns *ORA-01839: Date not valid for given month*. Only add_months has this end-of-month-workaround

Comment: @zᴉɹɥƆ - you're quite right. I'm trying to guess what the OP is doing to get the behaviour they describe in the question.

Comment: me too :) I guess it's just the program he's using to access the db